# R shiny: Interactive Toggle Points (nearPoints()) with dynamic data selection getting errors after updating

Tags: r, shiny

I have a question about the shiny app I built. The app I shared was working fine until I updated my `ggplot2` package. I got an error saying: `Error in nearPoints: nearPoints: not able to automatically infer xvar from coordinfo`. I don't know why it was working, but now it is not working.

The idea of this app is to build an interactive scatter plot with the selected data input.

Can anyone help me to figure out why I got this error?

Here is app.r:

```
library(shiny)    
ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,
           selectInput("vsselection", "Choose a vs:", 
                       choices =       names(table(data.frame(mtcars$vs))),selected=0),
           plotOutput("plot1", height = 350,
                      click = "plot1_click",
                      brush = brushOpts(
                        id = "plot1_brush"
                      )
           ),
           actionButton("exclude_toggle", "Toggle points"),
           actionButton("exclude_reset", "Reset")
      )
     )
    )
server <- function(input, output) {
# For storing which rows have been excluded
vals <- reactiveValues(
keeprows = rep(TRUE, nrow(mtcars))
)

output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
# Plot the kept and excluded points as two separate data sets
keep    <- mtcars[which(mtcars$vs==input$vsselection),][ vals$keeprows, ,    drop = FALSE]
exclude <- mtcars[which(mtcars$vs==input$vsselection),][!vals$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]

ggplot(keep, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point(color = "blue") +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, fullrange = TRUE, color = "black") +
  geom_point(data = exclude, shape = 21, fill = NA, color = "black", alpha =   0.25) 
})

# Toggle points that are clicked
observeEvent(input$plot1_click, {
res <- nearPoints(mtcars[which(mtcars$vs==input$vsselection),],   input$plot1_click, allRows = TRUE)

vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows, res$selected_)
})

# Toggle points that are brushed, when button is clicked
observeEvent(input$exclude_toggle, {
res <- brushedPoints(mtcars[which(mtcars$vs==input$vsselection),],  input$plot1_brush, allRows = TRUE)

vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows, res$selected_)
})

# Reset all points
observeEvent(input$exclude_reset, {
vals$keeprows <- rep(TRUE,    nrow(mtcars[which(mtcars$vs==input$vsselection),]))
})

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it figure out by updating the "shiny" package version to 1.0.0. So if you are using the old version, it would have warning: `Warning in seq_len(nrow(layout)) :
  first element used of 'length.out' argument`. This is something to do with the version of packages.